# Lower bounds for an expression of two positive integers?

Tags: asymptotics

Can we get an approximate lower bounds for the following expression:

$$\left(  1 + \frac{1}{ 2 \left( \frac{4^{nC}-1}{2^n-1} \right) }  \right)^{ \frac{1}{\left( \frac{4^{nC}-2^{nC}}{2^n-1} \right) } } -1$$

...where $n$ and $C$ are positive integers from around 10 to 1000?

**Or, alternatively, and better, can we get an upper bounds for the reciprocal of this function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is
$\left(  1 + \frac{1}{ 2 \left( \frac{4^{nC}-1}{2^n-1} \right) }  \right)^{ \frac{1}{\left( \frac{4^{nC}-2^{nC}}{2^n-1} \right) } } -1$.

Let
$g(n)
= \frac{4^{nC}-1}{2^n-1}
$
and
$h(n)
= \frac{4^{nC}-2^{nC}}{2^n-1} 
$.
You want
$f(n)
=(1+\frac1{2g(n)})^{1/h(n)}
$
(ignoring the "$-1$"
for now).

Since $C$
is moderately large,
$g(n)
\approx \frac{4^{nC}}{2^n}
=2^{2nC-n}
=2^{n(2C-1)}
$
and
$h(n)
\approx \dfrac{4^{nC}}{2^n}
= 2^{2nC-n} 
= 2^{n(2C-1)} 
$.

Letting
$D = 2C-1$
and
$a(n)
=2^{Dn}
$,
$g(n)
\approx a(n)
$
and
$h(n)
\approx a(n)
$
so
$f(n)
\approx (1+\frac1{2a(n)})^{1/a(n)}
$.

Looking at this,
I find myself asking
if you want
$a(n)$,
not $1/a(n)$,
in the exponent.
If this were the case,
the limit would be
$e^{1/2}$.

Similarly,
if you want
$a(n)$,
not $1/a(n)$,
in the internal expression,
the limit would be
$1$
(since $m^{1/m} \to 1$).

In your case,
$(1+\frac1{2a(n)})^{1/a(n)}
=e^{\ln(1+\frac1{2a(n)})/a(n)}
\approx e^{(1/(2a(n))/a(n)}
= e^{1/(2a^2(n))}
\to 1+1/(2a^2(n))
$.

Since you have that
"$-1$" in your expression,
subtract $1$ from these results.

(added later)

Since $e^x \approx 1+x$
for small $x$
and
$a(n) = 2^{Dn}$,
$e^{1/(2a^2(n))}-1
\approx 1/(2a^2(n))
=1/(2\ 2^{2Dn})
=1/2^{2Dn+1}
=1/2^{2(2C-1)n+1}
$

Comment: The expression does approach zero very fast.  However, I've been trying to get some sort of asymptotics that describe how quickly it approaches zero.  That's why I included the reciprocal in the question, because the reciprocal would grow large very quickly.  Anyways, I think I have what I need from your answer.  It may take a little time to review, but I'll probably accept it as is...

Comment: I completed the estimation of the result and corrected an error.